# data.frame columns and rows to a list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to create a list from data frame - each row should be represented by a list (that's easy part) but I have some columns which represent elements of one vector and I would like to merge them to one list-element.

Example:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 8:4
z <- letters[1:5]
a.1 <- rexp(5, 1)
a.2 <- rexp(5, 2)

df <- data.frame(x, y, z, a.1, a.2)

  x y z        a.1        a.2
1 1 8 a 1.75600452 1.07331010
2 2 7 b 0.65396344 2.24191595
3 3 6 c 0.02264465 0.92790284
4 4 5 d 0.39636223 0.13123314
5 5 4 e 1.09747016 0.08053996
```

Now I want to create for each line list like this, so desired output for the first row would be

```
list(x = df$x[i], y = df$y[i], z = df$z[i], a = c(df$a.1[i], df$a.2[i]))
$x
[1] 1

$y
[1] 8

$z
[1] a
Levels: a b c d e

$a
[1] 1.756005 1.073310
```

Is there any elegant way how to do that?

Comment: That requires parsing the colnames to recognize that a.1 and a.2 belong together. I think you'd be better off approaching this differently.

Comment: I suppose you can loop through the rows of df and construct a list with the ith row just as you have written. This would be functional, but not necessarily elegant/efficient.

Comment: @Frank Any idea how to deal with that? Arman, thanks for reply. This solution is obvious and my real data.frame is quite bigger, hence I would prefer to do it some smarter way (if possible)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why you're splitting a DF by rows, so I don't know a better way of approaching your real objective. For what it's worth if you had built it like `df <- data.frame(x, y, z); df$a = cbind(a.1, a.2)` then you could split by rows with `lapply(split(df, seq_len(nrow(df))), as.list)`

Comment: @Frank Thank you, this one works for me!